# Close acivity 'used as dialog' on Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget

I have an activity, which I used as a custom *loading dialog* (the dialog is pretty complex and has custom UI, which fits the customer colors schemes, etc.).

The *loading dialog* is created and shown from class, which is not derived from **Activity** class (this I am mentioning becuase the **startActivityForResult()** cannot be called):

```
  private void showLoadingDialog()
  {
    Intent intent = new Intent( this, ActivityDialogLoading.class );
    intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK ); 
    startActivity( intent );
    isLoadingDialogShown = true;
  }
```

The dialog is shown when long running asynchronous tasks are performed by the application on background.

Now when the background tasks if finished I want to close the *loading dialog* (The loading dialog has also the *Cancel* button, so client can interrupt the task, but this is other story).

I did not found a way to get the reference to the instance of the running **ActivityDialogLoading** class to call the **finish()** method...

The way I am using is a bit complicated - I override **BroadcastReceiver** so it takes the reference to the **ActivityDialogLoading** in its constructor. In **OnResume()** method of the **ActivityDialogLoading** I register as a receiver for broadcasted intent.

When I need to close the  *loading dialog* i broadcast the intent... Is there a better way? 
Saying the same with other words: What is the best way to close an activity when the close action is caused by some background event in application engine?